# What does multiply mean in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have seen this question today.

$[A \cdot(B-C)]\cap[(A \cup C)\cdot(C-B)]$

> 1.$(A-B) \cdot (A-C)$
>
> 2.$(A \cdot B)\Delta (A\cdot C)$
>
> 3.$(A \cup B)\cdot (A \cup C)$
>
> 4.$\emptyset$

Please don't give downvotes beacause I didn't try.I don't know the meaning how can I try:).

Comment: It can be the cartesian product. Anyway, cartesian product is in general denoted with $\times$.

Comment: The *can* be the cartesian product.  But if A,B, C are subsets of numbers it could be that $A \cdot B = \{a*b| a \in A; b \in B\}$.  That would be my first guess before cartesian product.  What does the triangle mean?

Comment: @fleablood .Then what's the answer here?

Comment: I dunno.  I'm too lazy and uninterested to figure it out.

Comment: @fleablood Triangle often denotes symmetric difference.  $A\triangle B = (A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B)$, the `xor` in logic.

Comment: Okay, if it means cartesian coordinates then $B - C$ and $C - B$ are disjoint so anything x (B - C) $\cap$ anything else x (C- B) will be the empty set.  If it it means the set of the products of the elements... well, I take it back... it probably doesn't mean the product as that would be utterly indeterminable unless we knew what the sets were.  So it probably *does* mean the cartesian product.  But don't take my word for it.

Comment: Where did the question come from?

Comment: So @JMoravitz what do you think the dot means?  I now doubt that it means either cartesian product nor multiplicative product.  If triangle is xor and union is or and intersection is and does dot mean... what?

Comment: @fleablood oh, I agree that it probably is intended to mean cartesian product, especially if this is for an elementary set theory class, but it is the first time I've ever seen it used in such a way.  I have **always** seen cartesian product using `\times` $\times$ before.  Still, worse decisions for notation have been made in the past...

Comment: I've googled and $\cdot$ is almost universally meant to $A \cdot B = \{a*b\}$.  But if so, I don't think this question has an answer.  (If A is all real and B is rationals and C is irrationals then this is .... all reals but different choices of set yield different results.)  If it means cartesian product then the answer is the empty set.  So I'm now assuming that this means cartesian product but... it's *not* conventional nor universal and is certainly ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\cdot$ stands for cartesia product. Then:

$$[A \cdot(B-C)]\cap[(A \cup C)\cdot(C-B)] = \emptyset$$
Let's prove this!

Notice that $$A \cdot(B-C) = \{(v,w) : v \in A ~\text{and}~ (w \in B ~\text{and}~w \not\in C)\}$$ while

$$(A \cup C)\cdot(C-B) = \{(x,y) : (x \in A ~\text{or}~ x \in C)~\text{and}~ (y \in C ~\text{and}~y \not\in B)\}$$

In order to find the intersection $[A \cdot(B-C)]\cap[(A \cup C)\cdot(C-B)]$ we need to find all couples $(v,w) = (x,y)$.

We can find some $v=x$, but we can never find $w = y$ since $w \in B$ and $y \not\in B$. Then the intersection is the empty set $\emptyset$.